# How access to database on routing file with Symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have to manage a multilingual routing as part of a Symfony2 project.
In order to get the whole URL translated i have to access the EntityManager from the PHP routing file to get the proper translation and the translated slugs.

Does anyone know how to do that ?

Thanking you,
Antoine.

Comment: Why do you need access to the DB from the routing ? does {slug} not work ? then you search the DB for the slug ?

Comment: I think, that this is not a good idea to generate routes config from DB each request, beacause of low performance. May be you should pre-generate routes file and update it every 5-15 minutes, for example by cron?

Comment: @ManseUK {slug} does work but i need a whole translated route.
Example : /domain/product/{productSlug_en}, /domain/produkt/{productSlug_de}, /domain/produit/{productSlug_fr} where "product", "produkt" and "produit" are translated keys stored in database.

Comment: I think your going to need to create the routes for the static parts ...

Answer (score 0):

May be you have to make separate third-level domain for each language (ru.site.com, fr.site.com) and generate routes using your database translation table from template?

Answer (score 0):

What I could suggest you is to check the [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle). This bundle let you define localized routes. Here ta copy of the overview text for the bundle taken from the documentation:

> ## Overview
>
> This bundle allows you to create i18n routes. Key points:
>
> - uses the Translation component; translate URLs just like you would translate    any other text on your website
> - allows you to use different hosts per locale
> - does not require you to change your development processes
> - can translate all routes whether they are coming from third-party bundles,   or your own application

I did not use it myself and I'm not the developer of this bundle and I don't know if it will work for your slug. But I hope this will help you in some ways.

Regards,
Matt